# authorizing a specific phone number in application

Tags: android, contacts

In my app a task is achieved but that is achieved whenever a sms is received but problem is that whenever from any number a sms is received that task is done which is giving me problems as i wanted to do that task whenever a sms is received from a specific number only. So how can i authorize a specific number in my app as well it should be depend on users choice to which number from their contact he/she wanted to authorize. Thank you in advance..

Comment: have you implemented the SMS broadcast? if yes, you can match the number you want to authorize with the one message received from!

Comment: Register a broadcast receiver for SMS, get contact in your OnRecive() method and put a check for that particular number before do your task.

Comment: Thank you @Saqib but to match number i have to specify a number in my SMS Broadcast but i want user to choose number from his/her contact for authorization.

Comment: do you still need a solution or you got the idea to implement it by yourself?

Comment: i got the idea but not by myself, above another answer helped me. @Saqib but i need a little more help to implement it.

Comment: Like in some app there are options choose from your contacts and user choose a number and that number is shown on textview beside the option.

Comment: so you want user to choose a single contact from list? on start of application? If so just load the list on start and let user choose a number, use shared preference to store number as far as the next number overrides it and match it with the required one